# Open all files in a folder (Different types: VBA, excel, word)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA code that loops through all the files in my folder.  The folder has different files which include .vbs, .doc,.pdt etc.  I have a code that opens everything in a workbook but wont work to open them in their correct format.  I tried different shell functions but that didnt work either.

```
Sub Looping()
'Step 1:Declare your variables
    Dim MyFiles As String
'Step 2: Specify a target folder/directory, you may change it.
    MyFiles = Dir("C:\Users\path of folder\")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
'Step 3: Open Workbooks one by one
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\path of folder\" & MyFiles

    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    'run some code here
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Step 4: Next File in the folder/Directory
    MyFiles = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you going to do with these files when you open them?

Comment: Do you try/want opening them in Excel?

Comment: @BigBen I just want to display them for a set time (right now 10 seconds) and then close the item and move to the next.  Almost making a slide show of different files.

Comment: @FaneDuru No I want to open them as their original source IE word document opens for a .doc file

Comment: I can show you how to open each such a file in its default application, but it looks complicated to close them after a specific period of time.  I have in mind a way, but not so easy to implement it for all possible files...

Comment: @FaneDuru as long as I dont have to declare the document name, I am okay with seeing your option.

Comment: @Tara what you are trying to do sounds cool. What is the reason you want to have a slideshow like that? What's the business case?

Comment: @zedfoxus Yes, we have tv's on the production floor and I want the tv to cycle through different documents/pdfs/etc that is relevant to the area.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer...

Comment: Please, test the answer code and send some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next updated sub. It will use the known applications for workbooks or Word documents to open/close them and `FollowHyperlink` to open the rest of extensions in their default application, then find their application process and terminate it.

**Edited**: In order to avoid that waiting sign I changed `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))` with `Sleep` API. Please, firstly copy the next API function on top of the module keeping the code (in the declarations area):\

```
 Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)
```

Then, the next updated code in the same module:

```
Sub Looping()
    Dim MyFiles As String, folderPath As String, strExt As String, wb As Workbook
    folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestCSV\"
    MyFiles = Dir(folderPath & "*.*")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
        strExt = Split(MyFiles, ".")(1)
        Select Case LCase(strExt)
            Case "xls", "xlsx", "xlsm", "xlsb", "csv"
                Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & MyFiles)
            Case "doc", "docx", "docm"
                Dim appWord As Word.Application, doc As Object
                Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                appWord.Visible = True
                Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(folderPath & MyFiles)
            Case "vbs"
                Dim cmdStr As String, strVBSPath As String
                strVBSPath = folderPath & MyFiles
                cmdStr = "cmd.exe /c """ & strVBSPath & """"
                Shell cmdStr, 0               
            Case Else
               ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink folderPath & MyFiles
      End Select
       DoEvents
         Sleep 5000 'for 5 seconds, 10000 for 10 seconds
         'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
       DoEvents
      Select Case LCase(strExt)
            Case "xls", "xlsx", "xlsm", "xlsb", "csv"
                wb.Close False
            Case "doc", "docx", "docm"
                doc.Close: appWord.Quit
            Case "vbs": 'do nothing in such a case...
            Case Else
                Dim exeApp As String
                exeApp = GetApplication("." & strExt)
                TerminateProcess exeApp 'it terminates the whole process.
                                                  'for a pdf file, even if some more files were open in Acrobat
                                                  'all files will also be closed when process is terminated...
      End Select
      
    MyFiles = Dir  'continue the loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

The other necessary functions:

```
Private Function GetApplication(ext As String) As String
   Dim strAppl As String, strPathExe As String, strExeFile As String, strODSfile As String
    Dim WSHShell As Object

    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    strAppl = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & ext & "\") & _
                                                                                  "\shell\open\command\")
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        GetApplication = ""
        MsgBox "No program installed for extension """ & ext & """"
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    strExeFile = Split(strAppl, """ """)(0)
    strExeFile = Right(strExeFile, Len(strExeFile) - 1)
    strExeFile = Right(strExeFile, Len(strExeFile) - InStrRev(strExeFile, "\"))
    GetApplication = strExeFile
End Function

Private Sub TerminateProcess(sExeName As String)
   Dim strComputer As String, objWMIService As Object, colItems As Object, objItem As Object
    strComputer = "."
    
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & sExeName & "'", , 48)
    
    For Each objItem In colItems
      objItem.Terminate
    Next
End Sub
```

There also are extensions (like .txt) for which the process cannot be returned in the above tried way. I think I can also find a way to determine the application window handler (based on its title containing the file name) and then extract the process from the window handler. But it is complicated and if you do not use text files, it will be a lot of useless work...

The code is not tested, but it should work. If a problem, I probably missed something minor, typos etc. In such a case do not hesitate to ask for clarifications, mentioning the error or whichever inconvenience you have.

Comment: I moved the select statement after the loop and now works perfectly!

Comment: the only issue is that the vbs has a warning message.  is there a way to bypass it in the code?

Comment: @Tara This cannot be possible... If you move Select statement outside the loop, it will process only the last file found in that folder. I am not sure I can get you... Saying "a warning message" is not elocvent at all. What warning message do you receive and for which file type? Theoretically it may happen if you try opening a file which may harm your computer (a .bat, vbs etc.) file.

Comment: @Tara I updated the code with about an hour before. I tried avoiding the waiting sign during `Wait`. The code uses now the `Sleep` API. I also corrected some parts of the code. Please, try it, but **as it is**... Now, I have to close my laptop. If something wrong, please specify what's happening and I will answer tomorrow.

Comment: *Update just changed it and it works great. The error I am getting is when I am running the VBS file and it says that this might harm my computer.  I have to click Okay to accept it to run. Is there a way to not have to click okay?

Comment: The code works perfectly but I am now trying to make a vbs code to automate the macro, it is not working however.  Do you have a code that would make this work?

Comment: @Tara I missed your comment from yesterday. I understood that you need to show something form different files... If you want running a vbs script I can adapt the code to do it. According to your UAC settings it will need permission or not. Now, I am not sure that I correctly understand the last question. Do you need VBS code to run the above code? If so, do you want it to open the workbook, run the sub and close it? What exactly, from what I mentioned (or something else) do you really need?

Comment: @Tara For now, adapted the code to also run a VBScript. If it ask for permissions, please try adding the folder you iterate sub in Excel Trusted Locations (Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings... - Trusted Locations: Add new locations, browse to the folder and press OK, OK, OK).

Comment: I assume that the TESTCVS should be the file path such as C:\....however when I add my file path I get that MyFiles is a bad file name.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Tara I still cannot understand anything... What "when I add my file path" should mean? **Where** do you try adding the path in discussion? Should this be part of a VBScript code to automate running of the above Sub?

Comment: I got it all to work, my issue now is that all the files will open on the icon bar but will not show on the screen. I am trying to add in a display so that will always come to the front of the monitor.

Comment: @Tara This should not happen. All started applications should take the focus. When you `make it work', did you modify the code? If so, can you tell me what did you modify? If not and not something confidential can you share the workbook you are using? Besides all that, can you clarify my previous questions regarding 'vbs code to automate the macro', 'adding the fille path'?

Comment: the MyFiles = Dir(folderPath & "*.*") comes up with a Bad file name or number

Comment: If you used it as you show it, it si wrong. It should be `Dir(folderPath & "*.*")`, but I think is only a typo here. This error is self explanatory: The path you supplied (`folderPath`) is wrong. It does not end in "\", or simple does not exist...

Comment: sorry I cant send any chats through this yet.  The code works perfectly but it has a lag when opening up each file.  I added Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) but that doesnt seem to be helping to open the files faster.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Tara Opening the file does not have anything to to with the waiting time to display it. I am afraid I do not understand what you mean. Anyhow, I am not satisfied with your way of answering. It should be obvious to explain **in which circumstances** the code raise `Bad file name or number` and after some time it doesn't... I cannot understand too much from the feedback received from you.

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, I mentioned that the code worked.  I took the fixes you mentioned and it works.  I dont know how my feedback isnt enough. Can you elaborate?  I am just now trying to make the macro run faster, meaning I do not have a delay opening all the items in the folder.

Comment: @Tara You said that the code works, before mentioning the 'Bad file name or number` issue... I did not mention any fix, since I did not see the code you use. I made some suppositions and you should confirm if one of them was the cause. Then, I told you  that opening itself has nothing to do with the programmatic delay. I tried replacing `Application.Wait` offering a variant not showing the waiting sign and being possible to be set of millisecond. You cannot do anything about the opening itself. If total time between two consecutive applications run is problematic, you can play with `Sleep`.